# Extracting span values on keypress with tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, keypress, tampermonkey

(I am mainly working with Matlab but i need some input data from a webpage to make it run. I'm entirly new to Javascript and any form of Grease/Tampermonkey.)

---

My intend is to get four certain span values everytime I press a key button from a webpage. I want to stack those values in an array and export them later into a csv.

The span values change on mouseover on the page. Idealy I move to cursor to the Data I need to get, press a key and get the Data saved.

I cannot get any of this to work. Using this function to call the Data, since there are 4 values with the same ClassName I am intending to cycle through the Index to get them all.

```
function readvalue(index){

    let text = document.getElementsByClassName("pane-legend-item-value")[index].innerhtml;

}
```

Maybe something like this to call on the kreypress?

```
if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();

    let v1 = readvalue(0);
    let v2 = readvalue(1);
    let v3 = readvalue(2);
    let v4 = readvalue(3);
    console.log(v1);
}
```

I would love to get some help here! Feel free to message me on Email if you have some spare minutes to help me out. (rage271@gmx.de)

I appreciate you reading this.

Cheers, Malte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Store Solution**

One solution is to store the value on a mouseover event and print the stored value when you press the enter key.

I think this solution is a bit tricky to get the correct value on a bigger webpage.

```js
let valueStore = '';

document.querySelectorAll('.pane-legend-item-value').forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
        valueStore = '';
        elem.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    });
    
    elem.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
        valueStore = event.target.innerHTML;
        elem.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    });
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        console.log(valueStore);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="pane-legend-item-value">value 1</div>
<div class="pane-legend-item-value">value 2</div>
<div class="pane-legend-item-value">value 3</div>
<div class="pane-legend-item-value">value 4</div>
```

**Position Solution**

the other solution is to store the mouse position and get the element with the `elementFromPoint` method.
But what happens when two elements are on top of each other?

```js
let x;
let y;

document.onmousemove = function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
};

function getElementAtMousePosition() {
    return document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        console.log(getElementAtMousePosition().innerHTML);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="pane-legend-item-value">value 1</div>
    <div class="pane-legend-item-value">value 2</div>
    <div class="pane-legend-item-value">value 3</div>
    <div class="pane-legend-item-value">value 4</div>
```

Comment: Hey there, you are already a legend to me for helping me! highly appreciated!
ReferenceError: event is not defined
is what I get unfortunately. Is there no such thing as simply "reading" the value in a span? adding the key as a trigger shouldnt be the main focus here right? <span class="pane-legend-item-value pane-legend-line pane-legend-item-value__main" style="color: rgb(153, 0, 0);">5.2933</span> is what I am trying to read off

Comment: :) I'm a little bit confused about the ReferenceError. Where do you get this one? When you like to get exactly that span you need to use the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the first element or use the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all matched elements as an array of type HTMLElement . 
You can write it like: `document.querySelectorAll('.pane-legend-item-value.pane-legend-line.pane-legend-item-value__main').innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the values easy with [jQuery's `.map()` function](https://api.jquery.com/map/) (and jQuery makes userscripting much easier and loads locally when used via `@require`).

Note that for the keyboard event handler:

- You should normally prevent the default action to prevent unexpected side effects.
- `keyup` and especially `keypress` can be suppressed in some cases.  Usually best to use `keydown` in this kind of scenario.

So, here is **a complete working userscript** (It's just the part above the `******` block).
To see it in action, Run the code snippet.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Grab span values on keypress
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $ */

$(window).keydown (keyboardShortcutHandler);

function keyboardShortcutHandler (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.key == "Enter") {
        grabStatsFromSpans ();

        zEvent.preventDefault ();
        zEvent.stopPropagation ();
        return false;
    }
}
function grabStatsFromSpans () {
    var zStats = $(".pane-legend-item-value").map (
        (K, node) => node.textContent.trim ()
    ).get ();
    console.log ("zStats: ", zStats);
}

/********************************************************************
******* Everything below this block is simulated target page. *******
******* It's NOT part of the userscript.                      *******
********************************************************************/
$("table").on ("mouseover", "td", zEvent => {
    var jSqr    = $(zEvent.target);
    var stats   = jSqr.data ("stats");
    $(".pane-legend-item-value:eq(0)").text (jSqr.text() );
    $(".pane-legend-item-value:eq(1)").text (stats[0]);
    $(".pane-legend-item-value:eq(2)").text (stats[1] === "m" ? "male" : "female");
    $(".pane-legend-item-value:eq(3)").text (stats[2].toLocaleString('en') );
} );
```

```css
table {border-spacing: 1em; margin: -1em;}
td {border: 1px solid gray; padding: 1em 2em;}
h3 {margin-bottom: 0;}
label {margin-left: 3em; width: 5em; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Click in this area.</strong> Then, Mouse over squares and press enter.</p>
<table><tr>
    <td data-stats='["human","m",1.1e3]'>Aksel</td>
    <td data-stats='["cat","f",7.3e7]'>Babette</td>
    <td data-stats='["dog","f",9.6e6]'>Cajsa</td>
</tr></table>
<h3>Stats:</h3>
<label>Name:    </label><span class="pane-legend-item-value"></span><br>
<label>Species: </label><span class="pane-legend-item-value"></span><br>
<label>Gender:  </label><span class="pane-legend-item-value"></span><br>
<label>Likes:   </label><span class="pane-legend-item-value"></span>
```